# Creating a model on a condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I have a User model (which I am thinking of renaming UserAccount for syntactic reasons)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :tutor, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Then I have a Tutor model

```
class Tutor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

However, I only want tutor info to be created if the is_tutor boolean is set to true. is_tutor is a column inside the User table.

Should this logic be added to a validation or to a condition inside the Users's has_one logic? And how would this be done?

Thanks!

Comment: at what point you want to create the tutor? after creating the user_account?

Comment: A user account is created. Then, the user can decide if they want to be students or tutors (or even both) by selecting a check_box in the edit account page.

Comment: so he will select this option and update his account, now, what happens when user edit his sccount again and uncheck that option?

Comment: if is_tutor is unticked, tutor row gets destroyed

Answer (score 1):

My idea if how this could be done.

**models/user.rb**

```
after_update :check_tutor

def check_tutor
  if self.is_tutor?
    Tutor.find_or_create_by_user_id(self.id)
  else
    self.tutor.destroy
  end
end
```

`after_update` callback will check everytime  a user is updated if user id or not a tutor.

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for indeed. Just one thing is unclear: the self.tutor.find_or_create_by_user_id...is this adding onto the user table? Or is it adding to the tutor table? If the latter, then why does it need self?

Comment: I modified the answer